# Sorting list according to idx attirbute of different list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have two lists I am working with, the first is a list of objects such that

```
A = [a1, a2, a3, a4]
```

and another list of objects which have an attribute calling an index, e.g.

```
B = [b1.idx==2, b2.idx==1, b3.idx==3, b4.idx==4]
```

My goal is to sort list A according to the idx attribute of the objects in list B, my resulting list for this example would thus be

```
C = [a2, a1, a3, a4]
```

I have done this using a for loop but I am curious if there's a more efficient way to do it. An example of my implementation is

```
C = []
for i in range(len(B)):
    C.append(A[B[i].idx])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension (carefull of the `-1` because array is 0-indexed) :

```
a_sorted = [A[B[i].idx - 1] for i in range(len(B))]
print(a_sorted)
```

The problem with sort is that it depends on the index, so you could do

```
a_sorted = sorted(enumerate(A), key=lambda idx_val: B[idx_val[0]].idx)  # [(1, 2), (0, 1), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
a_sorted = list(map(itemgetter(1), a_sorted))  # [2, 1, 3, 4]
print(a_sorted)
```

Comment: What do you mean by depends on the index? and why is that a problem?

Comment: @MortenNissov Normally the sort operation depends only on the object itself, not no its index, here you need to use the index from A to know the latter position

Comment: So the problem with the former solution is a question of good practice?

Comment: @MortenNissov it depends, if it's was you need to do this is ok. I'm just telling that the first solution with the list comprehension is better because you just put the object wher the index tells and that's it, **here, in this case** sorting is not the best way just that

Comment: @MortenNissov you can now think about accepting the answer so  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a pandas dataframe, then use the `sort_values` method:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[a1,a2,a3,a4],'B': [b1.idx, b2.idx, b3.idx, b4.idx],'C':[a2, a1, a3, a4]})
df = df.sort_values(by = ['B'])
```